# assets_audio_player package Music control when the mobile screen is locked

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am building a music player application, everything works fine, but when the phone screen is locked, the notification is disabled [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHHpy.jpg)

```
  getSongs() async {
List<SongInfo> artists =
    await audioQuery.getSongs(sortType: SongSortType.RECENT_YEAR);
for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
  int rr = math.Random().nextInt(9);
  songs.add(Audio.file(artists[i].filePath,
      metas: Metas(
          title: artists[i].title,
          artist: artists[i].artist,
          image: MetasImage.file(artists[i].albumArtwork),
          onImageLoadFail: MetasImage.asset('assets/$rr.jpg'))));
  infos.add(artists[i]);
}
assetsAudioPlayer.open(Playlist(audios: songs),
    showNotification: true,
    autoStart: false,
    loopMode: LoopMode.playlist,
    playInBackground: PlayInBackground.enabled,
    forceOpen: true,
    notificationSettings: NotificationSettings(
      playPauseEnabled: true,
      nextEnabled: true,
      prevEnabled: true,
      stopEnabled: true,
      seekBarEnabled: true,
    )
    // headPhoneStrategy: HeadPhoneStrategy.pauseOnUnplug,
    );
}
```

i use assets_audio_player package

> This problem is only in Android 9 and above

Please help me what is the solution?